# If someone eats in the succah anyways while it's raining, do they need to stay in the kosher part?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, weather

If it's raining, most people will go inside and not eat in the succah. If, however, someone chooses to stay and eat in the succah, must they stay in the kosher part, or is it OK to go into a non-kosher part?

It seems that since it's raining, there would be a *ptur* (exemption) from eating in the succah. But perhaps by staying outside, this guy negates his *p'tur* and must stay in kosher areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *Rama* 639:7 ("and whoever is exempt from *suka* and doesn't leave there… that's nothing but laity") as explained by *Beur Halacha* ("as [the pain of being in the rain] is a violation of *yom tov*"), if he's going to violate the *Rama*'s injunction and sit in the *suka* during a rainfall, then I'd say he should sit in the least uncomfortable spot, even if that's not normally a valid *suka* spot.

Comment: Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef (Orahh Hayim 635:4) [states](http://goo.gl/zxzeyC) (based on Hazon 'Ovadiah) that there is no Biblical prohibition in staying in the sukkah during rainfall; but, the person is still deemed *lay* as you cited.

Comment: Humbly, I would alter your final comment to read that "he **must** sit in the least uncomfortable spot". Since we are no longer concerned about his obligation of sitting in the sukkah (since he is exempt from this obligation due to rainfall), one could argue that we are now dealing with ["Wenishmartem me'od lenafshotekhem"](http://goo.gl/MJ9sko).

Comment: Who's translation is that?

Comment: if someone is going to sit in the sukah when it is raining he is doing so b/c of the simcha that sitting in the sukkah brings him no matter what the weather is and therefore sitting in an invalid are of the sukkah (not sure why you would have such an area) just to be unconfortable is idiotic and would not accomplish anything.

Comment: @DoubleAA, in the answer? Yours truly's.

Comment: @Dude So is getting simcha from sitting in a sukkah in the rain. If you are going to be idiotic and not accomplish anything by doing so anyway, might as well not be uncomfortable.

Comment: well that depends on what you are claiming not to accomplish anything. the point of eating in the sukkah even when it is raining is b/c one is not pained by the rain b/c the joy of fulfilling the mitzvah of eating in the sukkah is stronger. moving to an invalid part of the sukkah when it is raining would be the same is simply going inside

Comment: @Dude, if you can provide a source for the attitude+practice you're citing, I think it would belong in an alternative answer post. It seems, at least on its face, to be inconsistent with the sources cited in this answer.

Comment: @msh210 Just fyi the Rama does not agree with the position I presented in my answer. He thinks the issue with rain is a Chisaron in Dirah/Mitztaer as opposed to in Shem Sukkah.

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume that that last comment was a reply to my most recent edit. Well, no harm done with the edit -- but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Gra (Commentary to OC 639:5) a three-walled structure with a plant-based roof that has rain leaking in it is not a Sukkah at all. Thus it doesn't really matter where you sit because there is no Sukkah in the vicinity.